# Breaking out a dataframe into groups, applying a calculation, and reconsolidating to one dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I am having trouble breaking out my dataframe, applying a calculation, and putting it back together.

This is what my dataframe looks like:

```
Priority    ID      Name    Coverage    Group
1           1000    Name 1  33         Group A
2           1001    Name 2  67         Group A
3           1002    Name 3  100        Group A
4           1003    Name 4  33         Group B
5           1004    Name 5  67         Group B
6           1005    Name 6  100        Group B
7           1006    Name 7  33         Group C
8           1007    Name 8  67         Group C
9           1008    Name 9  100        Group C
```

I am trying to create a new "Effective Coverage" column, because my current "Coverage" column is cumulative for each "Group". So for instance, "Name 3", which is part of "Group A", actually has a coverage of 33 (100 - 67).

The end result that I am looking to achieve is this:

```
Priority    ID  Name    Coverage    Group   Effective Coverage
1          1000 Name 1  33          Group A 33
2          1001 Name 2  67          Group A 34
3          1002 Name 3  100         Group A 33
4          1003 Name 4  33          Group B 33
5          1004 Name 5  67          Group B 34
6          1005 Name 6  100         Group B 33
7          1006 Name 7  33          Group C 33
8          1007 Name 8  67          Group C 34
9          1008 Name 9  100         Group C 33
```

This is what I have so far:

```
for group in groups:

    effective_coverage = [df[df['group']==group].coverage.iloc[0]]

    for i in range(1,len(df[df['group']==group].placementID)):
        ecov = df[df['group']==group].coverage.iloc[i] - df[df['group']==group].coverage.iloc[i-1]
        effective_coverage.append(ecov)

    effective_coverage = pd.Series(effective_coverage, name='effective_coverage')

    print effective_coverage

    df[df['group']==group] = df[df['group']==group].join(effective_coverage)
    print df[df['group']==group]
```

I know the logic I take to calculate the effective coverage is correct, because for each group, it prints out the correct effective coverage of 33,34,33.

However, when I try and join the effective coverage series, and print out the dataframe of just one of the groups, it just returns:

```
Priority    ID  Name    Coverage    Group
1          1000 Name 1  33          Group A
2          1001 Name 2  67          Group A
3          1002 Name 3  100         Group A
```

And does not successfully join my newly calculated effective coverage.

Any thoughts here? I'm a big Python noob so I would love to hear of more elegant approaches to accomplishing this if anyone has one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom `split_cumsum` function, which calculates `Effective Coverage`

```
In [33]: def split_cumsum(grp):
   .....:     grp['Effective Coverage'] = grp['Coverage']
   .....:     grp['Effective Coverage'][1:] = np.diff(grp['Coverage'])
   .....:     return grp
```

And, then `apply` `split_cumsum` over `df.groupby('Group')`

```
In [34]: df.groupby('Group').apply(split_cumsum)
Out[34]:
   Priority    ID    Name  Coverage    Group  Effective Coverage
0         1  1000  Name 1        33  Group A                  33
1         2  1001  Name 2        67  Group A                  34
2         3  1002  Name 3       100  Group A                  33
3         4  1003  Name 4        33  Group B                  33
4         5  1004  Name 5        67  Group B                  34
5         6  1005  Name 6       100  Group B                  33
6         7  1006  Name 7        33  Group C                  33
7         8  1007  Name 8        67  Group C                  34
8         9  1008  Name 9       100  Group C                  33
```

Comment: Thanks John, I didn't quite appreciate what circumstances would make sense to create a function and apply it to a DataFrame, but this solution is definitely a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you could use `diff` in `groups`

```
In [53]: df['Effective Coverage'] = df.groupby('Group')['Coverage'].diff()

In [54]: df
Out[54]:
   Priority    ID    Name  Coverage    Group  Effective Coverage
0         1  1000  Name 1        33  Group A                 NaN
1         2  1001  Name 2        67  Group A                  34
2         3  1002  Name 3       100  Group A                  33
3         4  1003  Name 4        33  Group B                 NaN
4         5  1004  Name 5        67  Group B                  34
5         6  1005  Name 6       100  Group B                  33
6         7  1006  Name 7        33  Group C                 NaN
7         8  1007  Name 8        67  Group C                  34
8         9  1008  Name 9       100  Group C                  33
```

Then fill the `NaN` with values from `Coverage` column

```
In [55]: df['Effective Coverage'] = df['Effective Coverage'].fillna(df['Coverage'])

In [56]: df
Out[56]:
   Priority    ID    Name  Coverage    Group  Effective Coverage
0         1  1000  Name 1        33  Group A                  33
1         2  1001  Name 2        67  Group A                  34
2         3  1002  Name 3       100  Group A                  33
3         4  1003  Name 4        33  Group B                  33
4         5  1004  Name 5        67  Group B                  34
5         6  1005  Name 6       100  Group B                  33
6         7  1006  Name 7        33  Group C                  33
7         8  1007  Name 8        67  Group C                  34
8         9  1008  Name 9       100  Group C                  33
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `Coverage` column is a cumulative total, then the max value of the column would be the total for the group. I've changed your coverage numbers so that you can see what is happening with the groupby which is then joined to the original data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Priority': np.arange(1, 10), 'ID': np.arange(1000, 1009), 'Name': ['Name {0}'.format(i) for i in np.arange(1, 10)], 'Coverage': [33, 67, 100, 11, 22, 33, 67, 124, 200], 'Group': ['Group {0}'.format(i) for i in ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C']]})[['Priority', 'ID', 'Name', 'Coverage', 'Group']]

df2 = df.join(df.groupby('Group').Coverage.max(), on='Group', rsuffix='_max')
```

You can then just add the new column to calculate the effective coverage:

```
df2['Effective Coverage'] = df2.Coverage.divide(df2.Coverage_max)

>>> df2
   Priority    ID    Name  Coverage    Group  Coverage_max  Effective Coverage
0         1  1000  Name 1        33  Group A           100            0.330000
1         2  1001  Name 2        67  Group A           100            0.670000
2         3  1002  Name 3       100  Group A           100            1.000000
3         4  1003  Name 4        11  Group B            33            0.333333
4         5  1004  Name 5        22  Group B            33            0.666667
5         6  1005  Name 6        33  Group B            33            1.000000
6         7  1006  Name 7        67  Group C           200            0.335000
7         8  1007  Name 8       124  Group C           200            0.620000
8         9  1008  Name 9       200  Group C           200            1.000000
```